# There are two keyframes that do not work at the same time

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I have the two divs hat and key that I want to use in transitions. The div "hat" works but the other does not.  I do not know why the div "sock" does not work. It is the same as "hat" but still does not work. I have tried to change the @keyframe pageExitRight property from "right: 40" to "left: 40" still did not change anything.

```
    body {
    background-color: white;
}
.box {

    /*   TITLES OF CHOICES    */    

    position: relative;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10%;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#hat {
    animation-name: pageExitLeft;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    position: relative;

    background-image: url(hat.jpg);
    background-position: center;
}
#sock {
    animation-name: pageExitRight;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    position: relative;

    background-image: url(sock.jpeg);
    background-position: center;
}
div.box:hover{

    /*   CHANGE COLOR WHEN MOUSE HOVER  */ 
    opacity: 0.5;
} 

@keyframes pageExitLeft {
    from  {left: 40; opacity: 1}
    to    {left: -440; opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes pageExitRight {
    from  {right: 40; opacity: 1}
    to    {right: -440; opacity: 0}

}




<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box" id="hat" >hat</div>
        <div class="box" id="sock">sock</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to do something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWPzNx you need to add a `position` to the elements you're animating, and specify a unit in your css. if you want help solving this, share all of the relevant code you're using.

Comment: I'll update the code by adding the html as well

Comment: And yes, that's something that I'm trying to do but I have two circles with images that I want to slide out

Answer (score 0):

You are missing units inside the @keyframes. You say left: 40, right: 40, left: -440, right: -440, but you do not specify what these numbers are.

Try this css:

```
    body {
    background-color: white;
}
.box {

    /*   TITLES OF CHOICES    */    

    position: relative;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10%;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#hat {
    animation-name: pageExitLeft;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    position: relative;

    background-image: url(hat.jpg);
    background-position: center;
}
#sock {
    animation-name: pageExitRight;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    position: relative;

    background-image: url(sock.jpeg);
    background-position: center;
}
div.box:hover{

    /*   CHANGE COLOR WHEN MOUSE HOVER  */ 
    opacity: 0.5;
} 

@keyframes pageExitLeft {
    from  {left: 40px; opacity: 1}
    to    {left: -440px; opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes pageExitRight {
    from  {right: 40px; opacity: 1}
    to    {right: -440px; opacity: 0}

}
```

Comment: I tried it and still only the div with id="hat" completes the animation the other div with id="sock" does not move at all.